# bases of a group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Let $b_1$=(2,2)and $b_2$=(-4,4). Is $B_0$={$b_1,b_2$} a basis of $\Bbb Z^2$?

I don't think that it is a basis because you can't get all the numbers from it, but how do I prove this? I am honestly also not sure that my hunch is correct but I think that it is not a basis because I can't find anything that will make (1,0) which is in $\Bbb Z^2$

I don't have much else other than a hunch at this point but I can't think of any ways in which I can prove it or disprove this statement.

I also think that this would only give even numbers which would not make it a basis because it wouldn't span the odds, would this be something to prove by contradiction? I just can't think how I would prove that it does not span the odds.

Comment: You can prove it by noting that $n(2,2)+m(-4,4)= (2n-4m, 2n+4m)$ always has even components, hence cannot equal $(1,0)$, which has odd first component. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second coordinate of any point in $\langle b_1,b_2\rangle$ will be of the form $2m+4n$ for $m,n\in\mathbb Z$. The left-hand side is always even, so all points in the lattice will have even second coordinate, i.e. $(0,1)$ is not in the span and the given set is not a basis.